# Different output from getClass().getResource().getPath() depending on environment

Tags: java, eclipse, gtk

I'm writing an app in Java in Eclipse where I need to get the absolute path to an image I'm using.  I decided to use getClass().getResource().getPath(), and it works great when I'm running the app from Eclipse.

When I export the app to a JAR file, however, the image doesn't appear.  I put in a print statement to find out what was coming from the call above, and it turns out that in Eclipse it comes back with something like "/some/path/to/image.jpg" and when I run it from the JAR, it comes back with "file:/some/path/to/image.jpg".  I know the extra "file:" is what is causing the problem, but if I'm using getPath(), it shouldn't be there. Even weirder is why does it show up from the JAR but not in Eclipse?

Comment: A downvote without any explanation is not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need the path for? To construct a  `FileInputStream` with? If all what you want to do is to get an `InputStream` of the image, then just use [`Class#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

Comment: I'm using the Java GTK bindings, and I thought that I couldn't create a GTK Image object without using the path directly.  But upon reading the documentation more closely and reading your suggestion, it turns out I can create one from a byte array, so thanks!

Comment: In other words, you're going to hardcode the image as a byte array?